# Pinch Zoom and onClickListener for same layout not working in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, pinchzoom

I've tried to implement PinchZoom custom Layout in Android based on the below link.

https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602

At the same time implemented onClickListener for the same Layout. But, its not working properly when i click on a particular position in layout, Pinch Zoom is not working after OnClick Functionality. Other wise working fine.

How to resolve this?

Can anybody suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

No need to set onClick() method onTouch() will handle both the case.

package com.example.demo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img);

        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                    // single tap
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // your code for move and drag
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```