# How to handle onClick and Zoom-Gesture on same View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, android-gesture

I am currently working on a calculator application which has a scaleable NumPad with a lot of buttons:
[image: NumPad]

The Buttons on the NumPad should register user input when they are clicked. Additionally, if the user performs a zoom-gesture on the NumPad it should increase in size / decrease in size.

**What's my Problem?**
I want to handle onClick events if the user taps a button, but also handle a gesture if the user pinch-zooms on the buttons. How can I do that?
**GitHub Repo:** https://github.com/Max-We/TheCalculator

Answer (score 0):

Hi @FxMx you can have a look at this - [Pinch Zoom and onClickListener for same layout not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195760/pinch-zoom-and-onclicklistener-for-same-layout-not-working-in-android)

You can set a `ontouchlistener` on your NumPad layout and do nothing if its single touch and you can set `onClick listeners` to your NumPad buttons which can perform your register events.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I added an onTouchListener to my LinearLayout which checks for SingleTapConfirmed. The problem is, that it's never actually called when I tap on the NumPad. Any idea?

Comment: Your layout might be below your NumPad because of which your layout touch listeners are never called trying changing background col. and see if it's below or above if it's velow you won't see that and if it's above you won't see your NumPad.  You can keep the layout above and afterwards make it as transparent backgorund due to which ut won't be visible to users and you can handle touch events on that.

Comment: Hey, to clarify: With LinearLayout I mean the NumPad. I only have one LinearLayout which is called NumPad and contains the Buttons. You can see that in my source code. Any idea why the problem persists? If you can help me I'd gladly accept your response as an answer.